# document.write javascript Black jack game

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am trying to make a black jack game using javascript.

so far I have the dealer's card and the player's card. The problem occurs when the player decides to get another card. It seems like document.write is late in writing the string onto the webpage.

```
    while (totalP < 21)
        {
            r = confirm("Hit?");
            if (r==true)
            {
                document.write("<center><br>You chose to hit. </center>");
                p[counter] = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)];
                document.write("<center><br>" + x + "'s next card: " + p[counter] + "</center>");
                totalP = total(p, totalP);
                if (totalP > 21)
                {
                    for (var i=0; i<p.length; i++)
                    {
                        value = p[i].substring(0,p[i].length-1);
                        if (value == "A")
                        {
                            totalP = totalP - 10;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (i == p.length - 1)
                        {
                            document.write("<center><br>You busted. Total = " + totalP + " > 21. Dealer Wins!</center>");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The string "You chose to hit." shows up and even after i press ok. the text that should display the next card doesnt show up on the webpage and the confirm dialog box "You chose to hit." shows up again, until the second ok or until the player's card in hand is greater than 21.

If someone can help me on this it would be much appreciated. After researching on the internet and troubleshooting on my own, i can only think of the document.write being unreliable and slow compared to the other javascript code.

Comment: `document.write` should be banned from existence, as the name implies it completely overwrites the document when used after the document has initially loaded.

Comment: You must have stumbled on some tutorials leftover from the mid-90's. `document.write` is obsolete for a lot of good reasons, and the `innerHTML` alternative has been around for quite a while now. There is only one thing to remember about `document.write`: don't use it unless you know exactly what you're doing (in which case you will most probably not want to use it anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use document.write. As you see, it completely replaces the content of the document.

Instead of that you should create a HTML document with some HTML elements in which you can place text.

You can select HTML nodes by their id property. When you have a HTML node like this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

you can use

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
```

to access that div in your Javascript code. You can then use

```
div.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

to change the text of that div. You can also create new HTML elements like this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "I am a newly created div!";
var oldDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
oldDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Afterwards your HTML document will look like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Hello World!<div>I am a newly created div!</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks will do that then. I got another question, how abt if i wanted to prompt the user if he wants to play the game again. What is the best way that so that I can erase the previous game and start a new one?

Comment: @leggo When you have another question, please create a new question.